# How do you add caching to curl/wget?

Tags: curl, caching, wget

I have a [gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/trajano/82982c229948df445ada518d7c6273df/raw/952a15344a1913b02ab9e217da909908156369bc/stack-redeploy.pl) that I'd like to execute as part of my script.  But I'd rather avoid it downloading it off the network every time I need the script.

So one way I thought was to cache it, I could write a simple wrapper that does

```
if ! [ -e ~/.cache/stack-redeploy.pl ]
then
  curl -so ~/.cache/stack-redeploy.pl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/trajano/82982c229948df445ada518d7c6273df/raw/952a15344a1913b02ab9e217da909908156369bc/stack-redeploy.pl
fi
~/.cache/stack-redeploy.pl
```

But that's a bit cumbersome, and also doesn't provide a TTL so that it doesn't keep it forever in case I changed the content.

So I was wondering if there's a option for curl or wget (or some other utility that is available in scoop/brew/apt-get) that would do what I need.

Comment: instead of `curl -so` i'd recommend `wget --timestamping -o` - wget will check when it was last modified on disk, and compare that to the last-modified http-headers, and only download the script if the one on gist is newer than the one on-disk

Comment: though timestamping may work for the most part, it does not satisfy the TTL portion of my Q in which it will always connect.  However, it matches the example I provided.